# GraphQl Query to get Uniswap OHLC data through The Graph

Tags: uniswap, swaps, graphs

I tried searching through whole doc of The Graph but couldn't get a way to get OHLC data of Uniswap pair swaps.

Where can I find such a query. Is this even possible?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think it is possible with The Graph API. You will need to track the values yourself or use a service which is already doing this. I've found Bitquery to be one of the best as they index multiple DEXs under the same API. They have a limited free plan, their paid plans are expensive.